Data format for mixed effects model lme4
I have a dataset from participants that were assigned to a random condition (full factorial 3x3x3 design) that varies on Feedback (three levels), Content (three levels), and Design (three levels). Participants filled out a questionnaire (GAD-7) before using the intervention that they were assigned to (t0) and after they used the intervention (t2). Moreover, their expected affective, behaviour and cognitive engagement was measured before using the intervention (t0), and their experienced affective, behaviour and cognitive engagement during using the intervention (t1) and after using the intervention (t2).

As a first step to analysing these data, I am fitting mixed-effects models with GAD-7 as the outcome variable. The null model was defined as:
model.Anxiety.Time <- lmer(GAD_7_TOTAL ~ T + (1|IDnumber),
                     data = ParticipantsEngagementAnxiety_clean, REML = FALSE)

with the participants as a random effect and time as a fixed effect (since it would not be logical to exclude time in the null model I think).
Now, I want to see what the effects of engagement for the three timepoints are on the outcome, and also the condition that they were assigned to (content, feedback, design). For engagement, I for example fit this model:
model.Anxiety.Engagement <- lmer(GAD_7_TOTAL ~ T + behaviorEngagement + cognitiveEngagement +
                           affectiveEngagement + (1|IDnumber),
                     data = ParticipantsEngagementAnxiety_clean, REML = FALSE)

Yet, since there is no measurement of GAD_7_TOTAL at T = 1 and there are other missing variables I cannot do an ANOVA to compare the null model with the model that includes engagement as a fixed effect because they have a different number of observations. E.g. when I run this:
anova(model.Anxiety.Time, model.Anxiety.Engagement)

This can be solved by deleting the rows with missing values, but then all measurement at t1 are removed. Therefore, I started to believe that my data is not in the right format for the analysis. I have tried several alternatives (e.g. using the difference between t0 and t2 as an outcome variable, but then this variable has the same value for every observation which doesn't allow to include participant as a random effect anymore). It would be of great help if you could give me suggestions for a right format of my data to do this analysis! The dput() for the data is shown below:
sample_data <- structure(list(IDnumber = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 
65L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 
69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 
73L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 
82L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 
86L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 99L, 99L, 
99L, 100L, 100L, 100L), levels = c("1197", "4215", "4244", "4481", 
"4483", "4484", "4490", "4493", "4520", "4522", "4525", "4528", 
"4722", "4748", "4762", "5492", "5697", "5701", "5705", "5736", 
"5761", "5768", "5793", "5796", "5802", "5816", "5826", "5948", 
"6218", "6224", "6232", "6260", "6262", "6275", "6276", "6277", 
"6283", "6306", "6381", "6384", "6401", "6434", "6444", "6451", 
"6455", "6483", "6494", "6575", "6576", "6579", "6582", "6586", 
"6587", "6591", "6592", "6595", "6597", "6616", "6621", "6623", 
"6626", "6629", "6632", "6637", "6641", "6643", "6647", "6649", 
"6651", "6678", "6688", "6692", "6697", "6709", "6710", "6714", 
"6716", "6724", "6726", "6728", "6729", "6739", "6740", "6744", 
"6746", "6750", "6752", "6753", "6759", "6762", "6765", "6766", 
"6768", "6770", "6771", "6772", "6773", "6775", "6778", "6779"
), class = "factor"), Content = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Cognitive Behavioural Therapy", 
"Meaning and Purpose", "Positive Psychology"), class = "factor"), 
    Design = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Competitively Gamified", 
    "Nongamified", "Storyline"), class = "factor"), Feedback = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Avatar", 
    "Text only", "Video"), class = "factor"), T = c(0, 1, 2, 
    0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
    1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 
    2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
    0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
    1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 
    2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
    0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
    1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 
    2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
    0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
    1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 
    2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
    0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
    1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 
    2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
    0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2), behaviorEngagement = c(3, 
    3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2.5, NA, NA, NA, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 3.5, NA, NA, 4.5, 4, 4, 3.5, 2, NA, NA, 2.5, NA, 3.5, 
    3.5, 4, 4.5, 3.5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 
    3, 4, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 4, 4, 4.5, 5, 5, 5, 4, NA, 
    3.5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2.5, 3, 4.5, NA, 3.5, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 
    4.5, 3, 4, 4, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    4, 3, 3.5, 2.5, 4, 3.5, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 2.5, 4.5, 3, 3.5, 
    3.5, 2, NA, 3.5, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 
    3, 4.5, 3.5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3.5, 4.5, 3.5, 2.5, NA, 3, 3.5, 
    2, 2.5, 2, 4, 4, 3.5, NA, 3, NA, NA, 3, 1.5, NA, 4, 3, 3, 
    4.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 4, 3, 2.5, 2, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 
    4, 4.5, 4.5, 5, NA, 4, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, 2, NA, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 
    4, 3.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 1.5, 3, 2.5, NA, 4.5, 5, 4, 
    3.5, NA, NA, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3, NA, 4.5, 4, 4.5, NA, 2, 
    NA, 3, NA, NA, 3.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.5, NA, 2, NA, 4, 4, 
    4, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 4, NA, NA, 3, 2, NA, 4, 3.5, 4.5, 1.5, NA, 
    2.5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, NA, 3.5, NA, NA, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3.5, 
    3, 4, 3, 3.5, 4, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 4, 2.5, 4, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 
    4, 5, 3, 3.5, 3.5, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2), cognitiveEngagement = c(3, 
    3.66666666666667, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 3.33333333333333, 
    3, 4.66666666666667, 4, 4.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, 4.66666666666667, 
    4.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 4, 3.33333333333333, 
    3.66666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
    NA, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 
    4, NA, NA, 4.66666666666667, 4, NA, 3.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 
    NA, NA, 3.66666666666667, NA, 4, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 
    4.33333333333333, 5, 4.33333333333333, 4, 4.66666666666667, 
    3.33333333333333, 4, 3.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 3.66666666666667, 4, NA, 1.66666666666667, 
    4.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 4, 
    4, 4.33333333333333, 4, 4, 4, 4.66666666666667, 4, 3.66666666666667, 
    4.66666666666667, 4, 4.33333333333333, 4, 4, 4.33333333333333, 
    5, 2, 3, 4, NA, 3.33333333333333, 4, 4.33333333333333, 5, 
    4, 4.66666666666667, 4, 3.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 
    4, 3.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, NA, 3.66666666666667, 
    NA, 2.33333333333333, NA, NA, 2.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
    2.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 3, 2.33333333333333, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 
    4.66666666666667, 4, 3, 3.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 
    NA, 4, 3.33333333333333, 4, NA, NA, 1.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 
    2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 3, 3.33333333333333, 
    4, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 4, 3.66666666666667, 
    3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 
    4, 4, 4, NA, 3.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, NA, 3.66666666666667, 
    3, 4, 3.33333333333333, 4, 3.66666666666667, 3, NA, NA, 3.33333333333333, 
    3.33333333333333, NA, 4.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
    3.33333333333333, 4, 4.66666666666667, 5, 3.66666666666667, 
    3.66666666666667, 4, 4.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 
    4.33333333333333, 4, 5, 4.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 
    4.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 4, 4.66666666666667, 
    5, NA, 4.66666666666667, NA, NA, 3.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 
    3, 3.66666666666667, NA, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
    4, 4, 3.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.66666666666667, 
    4, 3.66666666666667, 3, 1, 4, 4.66666666666667, 4, 4, NA, 
    2.33333333333333, 4, 4, 3.66666666666667, 4, 3.66666666666667, 
    4.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 4, 3.66666666666667, 
    NA, 2.33333333333333, 1.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 
    NA, NA, 3.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.66666666666667, 
    NA, 3.66666666666667, NA, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
    4, 3.66666666666667, 3, 2, 3.66666666666667, NA, NA, 3.33333333333333, 
    3, NA, 3.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 4, 4, NA, 2.33333333333333, 
    3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 4, 3.66666666666667, 
    4, 3.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, NA, 4, 3.33333333333333, 
    3, 4, 4.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 
    3.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 4, 4.66666666666667, 
    3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 
    4.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 
    3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 4, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4, 3.33333333333333), affectiveEngagement = c(3, 
    3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, NA, NA, 
    NA, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, NA, 
    NA, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, NA, NA, 4, NA, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 2, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, 4, 3, 3, 2, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
    3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, NA, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, NA, 2, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, NA, 
    4, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 3, 3, 3, NA, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, 
    4, 3, NA, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 4, 3, 5, 5, NA, 4, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 4, NA, 3, 3, 3, 5, 
    3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, 3, 1, NA, 4, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 1, NA, 4, 5, 5, NA, 4, NA, 3, NA, NA, 2, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 3, NA, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, NA, 3, 3, 5, 3, NA, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, NA, 4, NA, NA, 4, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, NA, NA, 
    NA, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2), GAD_7_TOTAL = c(14, 
    NA, 18, 23, NA, 17, 14, NA, NA, 8, NA, 11, 14, NA, NA, 23, 
    NA, NA, 24, NA, 17, 10, NA, 15, 9, NA, 8, 17, NA, 12, 16, 
    NA, NA, 10, NA, NA, 18, NA, 8, 13, NA, NA, 18, NA, NA, 9, 
    NA, NA, 14, NA, NA, 26, NA, 28, 23, NA, 19, 26, NA, NA, 16, 
    NA, NA, 14, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, 24, NA, NA, 14, NA, 13, 16, 
    NA, NA, 12, NA, 14, 17, NA, 13, 13, NA, 10, 13, NA, NA, 16, 
    NA, 9, 12, NA, NA, 16, NA, 14, 18, NA, 13, 16, NA, NA, 17, 
    NA, NA, 21, NA, 16, 19, NA, 17, 8, NA, 7, 16, NA, NA, 16, 
    NA, NA, 18, NA, NA, 13, NA, NA, 15, NA, 13, 15, NA, 15, 22, 
    NA, 12, 14, NA, 19, 18, NA, 19, 19, NA, 23, 14, NA, NA, 17, 
    NA, 15, 13, NA, NA, 21, NA, NA, 13, NA, NA, 18, NA, NA, 13, 
    NA, NA, 26, NA, 17, 15, NA, 11, 17, NA, 13, 21, NA, NA, 19, 
    NA, 15, 22, NA, NA, 21, NA, NA, 15, NA, NA, 26, NA, NA, 22, 
    NA, 14, 17, NA, NA, 16, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, 14, NA, 15, 27, 
    NA, 22, 18, NA, NA, 12, NA, NA, 13, NA, NA, 21, NA, NA, 13, 
    NA, NA, 13, NA, NA, 15, NA, NA, 14, NA, NA, 11, NA, NA, 14, 
    NA, 12, 15, NA, 15, 13, NA, NA, 16, NA, NA, 18, NA, 22, 16, 
    NA, 13, 22, NA, 19, 16, NA, NA, 11, NA, NA, 12, NA, 10, 14, 
    NA, NA, 15, NA, NA, 8, NA, 7, 10, NA, 9, 17, NA, 18, 13, 
    NA, NA, 11, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, 18, NA, NA, 13, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-300L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


Yet, since there is no measurement of GAD_7_TOTAL at T = 1 and there are other missing variables I cannot do an ANOVA to compare the null model with the model that includes engagement as a fixed effect because they have a different number of observations.---I'm confused by this statement. Why is this the case again?

This is because engagement was measured at T1, but not GAD_7_TOTAL. As far as I know, lme4 does listwise deletion for observations that have a NA value. So if I compare the model with the null model using an anova it gives an error message:
Error in anova.merMod(model.Anxiety.Time, model.Anxiety.Engagement) :
models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset

The reason you are losing observations has nothing to do with the outcome and everything to do with the predictors. All rows in which a predictor is missing are excluded from the analysis. To verify that the problem is not about the outcome, I first filtered out time 1, when GAD was not collected.
library(dplyr)
dat_02 <- sample_data %>% filter(T != 1)

Then I ran both of your models on the dat_02 dataset. I am going to include information about sample size from the results summary.
summary(model.Anxiety.Time)
Number of obs: 143, groups:  IDnumber, 100

summary(model.Anxiety.Engagement)
Number of obs: 114, groups:  IDnumber, 82

These are the exact same sample sizes reported when using the full dataset with timepoints 0, 1, and 2. Accordingly, the reason you are losing observations is because of the missingness on the engagement predictors.
To recover missing data, you need to convince yourself that the data is either missing completely at random (MCAR) or missing at random (MAR), which would allow you to utilize packages such as mice to impute the data. The other missing data mechanism, not missing at random (NMAR), is much more difficult to deal with. See this CV answer for clear definitions and intuitions behind these missing data issues.
